# Playing a short .wav on a layout in Android

Tags: android, layout, audio, wav

In android, I have a View Flipper that has a child on it that I would like to play a short .wav on when it is accessed some of the time (basically on random).

Is there a quick and easy way to play that wav right when the xml layout is accessed by the user?

I have a main class with a bunch of methods, so I can't really place it in onCreate...the layout page is shown based on when the user clicks a button - and it is all in a Linear Layout on a view Flipper

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play the sound when the view flipper "flips" to that view.  Something like:

```
mFlipper.showNext()
if(mFlipper.getCurrentView() == mSoundView)
{
    // Play audio
}
```

Comment: With what method should the mSoundView call the wav file?  Like a sound pool?

Comment: Yes.  Sound pool would be the way to go.